# how do I determine what is the country code of the calling numbers?

Tags: php, mysql

I am supposed to find out what country the call is originated from by reading the country code out of the number.

```
Sample Calling Numbers:

+18098998343 [Dominican Republic] Code: +1809
+18006005001 [US] Code: +1
```

The Challenge is that the country code numbers are different from one to four digits. I have a list of all countries with their calling code in my mysql database.  What could be the best possible way to detect the country code?

Comment: You'd probably have to take into consideration the entire length of the string. If the length of string is consistent then you can ascertain that the country code will have to be in the first 4 (not including the +) characters. If the string is not consistent in length, pad out the first few chars with numbers (0s) until it reaches the string length it should (11 Characters not including the +) then you can chop up the 4 characters in that minus the first few 0s that show up. I can see some flaw in my logic though, so it's probably not the answer, but hopefully you can make something out of it

Comment: Note that the Dominican Republic is an unusual case — they are part of the North American Numbering Plan, so they exist as a set of area codes under the `+1` country code. The same is true of many other Caribbean countries, as well as Canada.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over all known countrycodes and check, whether your phone number starts with. Once there are more than one hit, choose the longest hit.